# How to link some field in test/java/application.properties to the same field in main/java/application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There are fields`abc=def`in `test/resources/application.properties` and `main/resources/application.properties`. If I need to change both fields to `abc=ghi`, I need to operate twice. What is worse is that, it will be risky if I just change one but forget to change the other. Can I link those two fields, such that I just need to change it in one place?

Comment: Why dont you write a test for this use case then?

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to have the property defined in two different locations. You can simply access the value from `application.properties` in your test classes using `@Value("${abc})`. Use the `application.properties` file in the `test -> resources` directory if you want to override specific values.